# Display the fields of a ForeignKey relation in the template

Tags: django, templates, foreign-keys

I need help to display the fields of a table that is a ForeignKey relationship in a Template.

**models**

```
    nome = models.CharField (max_length=25,null=False, blank=False)
    revisao = models.CharField (max_length=20,null=True, blank=True)
    pit = models.ForeignKey(PIT, related_name='pit', on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name= 'PIT - Plano de Inspeção e Teste')

class PIT(models.Model):

    nome = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False, blank=False)
    fluido = models.ManyToManyField(Fluido, related_name='fluido', blank=True, unique=False)
```

In the IEIS Class I have the PIT field as FK. I need to display in the IEIS view template, some fields from the PIT class.

**views**

```
    ieis = IEIS.objects.get(pk=pk)
    especs = ieis.especificacao.all()
    fluidos = ieis.fluido.all()
    pits = PIT.objects.get(pk=pk)
   return render(request, 'ieis/view.html', {'ieis': ieis, 'especs': especs, 'fluidos': fluidos, 'pits': pits,})
```

**view.html**

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
      <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">nome</th>

            <th scope="col">RX_AN</th>

        </tr>
      </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>

                {% for pit in pits %}
                    <td>{{ pit.nome }}</td>

                   <td>{{ pit.rx_an }}</td>
                {% endfor %}

            </tr>
      </tbody>
</table>
```

Thank you in advance for all your attention, suggestions and dedicated help!

Comment: your question is too much confusing for me. If you are still in trouble, please describe your problem again, So I can help you

Comment: I can't get the fields from the PIT model and list them in the template. The view is to view the data from the IEIS to return correctly. But the PIT fields return only the object (queryset) and not the fields.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access the fields from PIT class, Then follow the code below.

```
    <tbody>
        <tr>

        {% for i in ieis %}
            'nome' from Model IEIS:    {{ i.nome }}  
            'revisao' from Model IEIS: {{ i.revisao }}
            'nome' from Model PIT:     {{ i.pit.nome }}
        {% endfor %}

        </tr>
  </tbody>
```

You can get those fields like this.

Comment: what is your template name. `ieis.html` or `view.html`. and can you show your updated template and views.py

Comment: I have updated the code.  The template name is view.html. Between comings and goings I arrived at this point. I fixed the PIT id and was able to get the fields. pits = PIT.objects.filter (id__in=[1]). But this ID must be according to the one saved in the IEIS table.

Comment: I solved it with this: pits = PIT.objects.filter (id__in=[pk])
Thank you very much for your attention and suggestions.